# Create Task Dialog: What is the meaning of "Configure for" option?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task

I am adding a new task to a Windows Server as local admin.  At the bottom of the Create Task dialog, I see an option "Configure for".  What is the meaning of these choices?

To be clear, this screenshot is from Windows Server 2016 (but I cannot a tag for that version).

[image]